# *Homework help * Inventory Program Part 3 (subclass)

Tags: java, subclass

I am trying to put the restock fee in the DVD subclass movieTitle. Edited my code as the way it should be, but it does not work . DVD is the parent class and movieTitle is the subclass. I am trying to get the method restock fee from the subclass into the parent class... Please help. I do not know how to call the method from the subclass to be usable in the parent class where it needs to print out. I have found places that explain subclasses and inheritance, but not how to implement the subclass features (methods).

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: inventoryprogrampart3.DVD.movieTitle.restockFee
    at inventoryprogrampart3.DVD.toString(DVD.java:126)

Instructions:

Modify the Inventory Program by creating a subclass of the product class that uses one additional unique feature of the product you chose (for the DVDs subclass, you could use movie title, for example). In the subclass, create a method to calculate the value of the inventory of a product with the same name as the method previously created for the product class. The subclass method should also add a 5% restocking fee to the value of the inventory of that product.
Modify the output to display this additional feature you have chosen and the restocking fee.

```
 <code>
 import java.util.Arrays;
 public class InventoryProgramPart3 {


 public static void main(String[] args) {



  DVD[] myDVD = new DVD[5]; // create array of DVD's

  // inventory of DVD's
   DVD p1 = new DVD ( 1, "Fast and Furious 6", 8, 5 );
   DVD p2 = new DVD ( 2, "The Matrix Reloaded", 8, 5 );
   DVD p3 = new DVD ( 3, "In Pursuit of Happiness", 8, 5 );
   DVD p4 = new DVD ( 4, "Darknet", 8, 5 );
   DVD p5 = new DVD ( 5, "Goonies", 8, 5 );


  myDVD[0] = p1;
  myDVD[1] = p2;
  myDVD[2] = p3;
  myDVD[3] = p4;
  myDVD[4] = p5;


         double total = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

    { 
    total +=  myDVD[i].getInvValue(); 
  }

    // Display the total value of the inventory on the screen

 //sorting DVD's alphabetically
 Arrays.sort(myDVD);

 for(DVD s: myDVD)

     {
 System.out.println(s);
 }

 System.out.println();
 System.out.printf("Total value of the entire inventory is: $ %.2f", total); 
 System.out.println();

 } // end main method
 }//end class 





 package inventoryprogrampart3;

 @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
 class DVD implements Comparable

 {
 private String thisTitle;
 private double thisStock;
 private double thisPrice;
 private double thisItem; 


 public DVD( double item, String title, double stock, double price )

 {
 thisItem = item;
 thisTitle = title;
 thisStock = stock;
 thisPrice = price;
 }// end constuctor

 // Getters and setters        

 public void setTitle(String title)

    {
thisTitle = title;
}//end method setTitle


//return Title
public String getTitle()

    {
return thisTitle;
}//end method getTitle

//set Stock
public void setStock(double stock)

    {
thisStock = stock;
}//end method setStock

//return Stock
public double getStock()

    {
return thisStock;
}//end method get Stock

public void setPrice(double price)

    {
thisPrice = price;
}//end method setPrice

//return Price
public double getPrice() 

    {
return thisPrice;
}//end method getPrice

public void setItem(double item)

    {
thisItem = item;
}//end method setItem

//return Item
public double getItem()

    {
return thisItem;
}//end method getItem

//calculate the inventory value
public double value()

    {
return thisPrice * thisStock;
}//end method value

public double getInvValue()

    {
    double invValue = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
         invValue = value();
        }
    return invValue;        
    }

    @Override
public int compareTo (Object o)

    {
 DVD s = (DVD)o;
 return thisTitle.compareTo(s.getTitle());
 }

     @Override
public String toString() // 



    {
  System.out.println();
 **return "Item number is: \t\t" + thisItem + "\nProducts Title is: \t\t"+ 
 thisTitle+"\nPrice: \t\t\t\t$" + thisPrice + "\nQuantity: \t\t\t"
             + thisStock + "\nValue: \t\t\t\t$" + value() + "\nRestock fee: 
  \t\t\t$" + restockFee()  ;**   <-- error here..........
   restock method is in the subclass (movieTitle), and do not not how to    
   implement it here in the parent class. 


    }         //end main method
    }        // End DVD class



package inventoryprogrampart3;

class movieTitle extends DVD {

private double thisRestockFee;// Restock fee to add to the inventory value

public movieTitle(double item, String title, double stock,
        double price, double restockFee) 
{
    super(item, title, stock, price);
    thisRestockFee = restockFee;
}


public double restockFee() {
    return super.getPrice() * .05;
}// end method value
} // End movieTitle class

</code>
```

Comment: You can call the method `restockFee()` in DVD by `super.restockFee()` from a method in movieTitle.

Answer (score 0):

Make DVD abstract and change restockFee to look like this

```
public abstract double restockFee();
```

Now movieTitle should look like this

```
class movieTitle extends DVD {

    private double restockFee1;// Restock fee to add to the inventory value

    public movieTitle(double item, String title, double stock,
            double price, double restockFee) {
        super(item, title, stock, price);
        this.restockFee1 = restockFee;
    }

    @Override
    public double restockFee() {
        return super.getPrice() * restockFee1;
    }// end method value
} // End movieTitle class
```

Since super doesn't have implemented restockFee it will call child's implementation. And in test use movieTitle.